# Request not supported: ExportToExcel

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I installed SP1 UR4 on CRM 2013 on premise (version 6.1.4.145 - DB 6.1.2.112).
After installation, I'm getting below error when I export to excel from the advanced find.

I try with changing the browser, Excel export is not working again.
I create new organization after UR4. The new organization able to export excel but the old one is not exporting excel anymore.
Has anyone run into the same problem?

Trace logs like below;

```
1* No sdk message requests found for key: ExportToExcel#2011/Organization.svc

2*
at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Boolean isFlowControlException) ilOffset = 0x7
at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode) ilOffset = 0x5
at SdkMessageRequestCacheLoader.LoadCacheData(SdkMessageRequestKey key, ExecutionContext context) ilOffset = 0x145
at ObjectModelCacheLoader`2.LoadCacheData(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context) ilOffset = 0x31
at CrmSharedMultiOrgCache`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context) ilOffset = 0x86
at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.GetRequestDescription(String requestName, IOrganizationContext context) ilOffset = 0x0
at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse, Boolean checkAdminMode) ilOffset = 0x2D
at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode) ilOffset = 0x2D
at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode) ilOffset = 0x26
at InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request) ilOffset = 0x34
at PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal() ilOffset = 0xF6
at ExportToExcelCommand.Execute() ilOffset = 0x6
at ExportToExcelPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) ilOffset = 0x4C
at Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) ilOffset = 0x22
at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x8A4
at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x3C
at Page.ProcessRequest() ilOffset = 0x14
at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) ilOffset = 0x33
at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() ilOffset = 0x18D
at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) ilOffset = 0x15
at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) ilOffset = 0x10A
at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) ilOffset = 0x5C
at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) ilOffset = 0x16A
at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType) ilOffset = 0x4B
Crm Exception: Message: Request not supported: ExportToExcel, ErrorCode: -2147220715

3* 
MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Error Number: 0x800608C7
Error Message: Failed to generate excel.
Error Details: Failed to generate excel.
Source File: Not available
Line Number: Not available
Request URL: crm2013.abc.co.uk/.../print_data.aspx
Stack Trace Info: [CrmException: Failed to generate excel.]
at Microsoft.Crm.Controls.ExportToExcelPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.] at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

4*
at CrmException..ctor(String formattedErrorMessage, Int32 errorCode, Object[] arguments) ilOffset = 0x30
at ExportToExcelPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) ilOffset = 0x4C
at Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) ilOffset = 0x22
at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x8A4
at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x3C
at Page.ProcessRequest() ilOffset = 0x14
at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) ilOffset = 0x33
at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() ilOffset = 0x18D
at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) ilOffset = 0x15
at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) ilOffset = 0x10A
at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) ilOffset = 0x5C
at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) ilOffset = 0x16A
at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType) ilOffset = 0x4B
Crm Exception: Message: Failed to generate excel., ErrorCode: -2147088185

5*
at ExportToExcelPage.AddExceptionToTrace(CrmException crmException) ilOffset = 0x2D
at ExportToExcelPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) ilOffset = 0x4C
at Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) ilOffset = 0x22
at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x8A4
at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x3C
at Page.ProcessRequest() ilOffset = 0x14
at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) ilOffset = 0x33
at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() ilOffset = 0x18D
at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) ilOffset = 0x15
at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) ilOffset = 0x10A
at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) ilOffset = 0x5C
at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) ilOffset = 0x16A
at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType) ilOffset = 0x4B
Request not supported: ExportToExcel

6*
at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Boolean isFlowControlException) ilOffset = 0x7
at CrmException..ctor(String message, Int32 errorCode) ilOffset = 0x5
at PlatformCommand.CreateCrmExceptionFromServiceFault(FaultException`1 fe) ilOffset = 0x1B
at PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal() ilOffset = 0xF6
at ExportToExcelCommand.Execute() ilOffset = 0x6
at ExportToExcelPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) ilOffset = 0x4C
at Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) ilOffset = 0x22
at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x8A4
at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) ilOffset = 0x3C
at Page.ProcessRequest() ilOffset = 0x14
at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) ilOffset = 0x33
at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() ilOffset = 0x18D
at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) ilOffset = 0x15
at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) ilOffset = 0x10A
at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) ilOffset = 0x5C
at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) ilOffset = 0x16A
at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType) ilOffset = 0x4B
Crm Exception: Message: Request not supported: ExportToExcel, ErrorCode: -2147220715
```

Comment: I'd raise a support ticket, looks like something went wrong with the upgrade.